# What is the difference between empty space (>> >> >>) and empty space(......) in eclipse ide?

Tags: eclipse

I know that,empty space (>> >> >>) in eclipse occurs due to use of keyboard(Tab) and empty space(......) occurs in eclipse due to use of Keyboards(Space bar) in the java editor.

What is the significance of it in programming and in the editors? Why is it shown differently in the Eclipse editors? What is the actual use of it and where it helps?

Can it allow to represent in the same way for, characters like new line(\n),vertical tab (\v),form feed (\f) etc.?

Comment: It makes seeing the difference between *types* of *common indent white space*; in particular the two nemesis of the **Tabs Vs Spaces War**. Visual Studio does the same thing "->" for tabs, "." for spaces when visible-whitespace is enabled. (In Java it "doesn't matter" semantically, and it still matters to ensure good consistent code layout, whatever 'side' is chosen!) If this can be extended to other whitespace characters.. that'd be a Eclipse feature (or lack of). VIM can show such other characters.

Comment: Indentation is useful to improve readability of the code. And some people like to indent their code with tabs, other with spaces. That's about it. Except for some languages like Python (and others based on it) where indentation is part of the language structure and denotes scope.

Comment: In Java there is no difference between tabs and spaces as far as the programming language is concerned - they are all just white space. Which you use is a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways of indenting: spaces, tabs and hybrid.

- Spaces are environment-invariant: if you are indenting by two spaces, it will be two spaces in every terminal, every editor. Different programming languages have different coding style mores. E.g. Ruby is usually written with two-space indents, Python with four-space ones. Some people like space-based indentation, and can be very vocal about it.
- Tabs will usually see people indenting by exactly one tab. It is up to the environment how to display it. The default is usually one tab in every 8th column, but editors will usually be able to adjust this. That way, if you disagree with a colleague about how many spaces are best, each can set their own environment as they wish. Some people like tab-based indentation, and can be very vocal about it.
- Hybrid is a nightmare. If you mix spaces and tabs, expect trouble, as it will typically happen that you will encounter pieces of code that are horribly misformatted, wherever *that* colleague touches it. Avoid hybrid indentation at all costs. The only people who don't absolutely hate hybrid indentation are those who haven't dealt with it yet, or don't understand why any of this is happening.

Now, it is very hard to avoid the hybrid indentation if you don't know which indentation method is actually present in the file, especially if your editor is helpfully emulating tabs when you have space indentation, e.g. by deleting the whole indentation level when you press a single backspace (as is normal in most editors).

Furthermore, there are some horrible programming languages (such as Whitespace and Makefile) that semantically distinguish spaces and tabs, and it is thus critically important to see what each character actually is.